# determine if a path is relative or absolute

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a simple regex to determine if a path is relative, or a hash?

I want to match these:

```
../index.php  
js/funct.js  
./home/
php/file.php?url=http://www.google.com
index.html#about=http://www.google.com
```

but not these:

```
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
/index.php
/
//google.com
#div4
```

here's what I have so far:

```
/^[^#\/]|\/\//.test(url)
```

But it's not working. Is there any way to get this to work?

btw I realize that `//google.com` is technically relative but I still don't want to match that case

I need this to be able to tell if I need to deal with a link after a pushState. Consider if I started on `/` and then `pushState`d to `/page1/` then a link that has a href of `'index2.html'` was supposed to go to `/index2.html` but will now go to `/page1/index2.html`

So I need to check for those types of relative paths.